# Need a delay to wait for GPS

Tags: objective-c, gps, timing

Using the iPhone and objective C, is there a way to stall or perform a timing loop to allow for the GPS to catch up and return a valid set of coordinates?

Currently, the application runs too quickly and the GPS cannot supply the coordinates fast enough...

Answer (score 4):

Since you said you're on iPhone, you're using CLLocationManager. Just set a delegate on the manager and wait for the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` message to know when the GPS data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your GPS polling is running in a different thread to the User Interface, you can call the static NSThread functions [sleepForTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepForTimeInterval%3a) or [sleepUntilDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepUntilDate%3a) from the thread that is waiting for the GPS data.

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile application is using GPS, your application should be prepared for location updates, even if your application doesn't track movements..
A common case would be where the user put your application in background and activate it later on a completely different location.

On iOS, create an implementation of [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) like Anomie wrote. And use the timestamp of the update to evaluate the freshness of the location.

Don't sleep & poll like other people suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Either block to wait for data or don't update anything if no data received. There is of course `usleep()`, but without showing code and specifically how your loop is executed and by what mechanism (threaded or not) we can only answer in general terms.

Comment: Don't use usleep(). Use NSTimer or performSelectorAfterDelay:.